# Difference between directly setting a controller's view and adding view as a subview

Tags: iphone

I have just started learning objective-C and the iphone sdk and I have a question that I hope someone can help shed some light on.

What is the difference in the following:

```
self.view = someView;
```

and

```
[self.view addSubView: someView];
```

Say for example, in a simple app, where we have only one controller and one container view (has a few image subviews).
What is the difference between the two statements? The reason that I'm asking is because I was tinkering around in some sample code and I noticed the view was being initialized with images as subviews like so:

```
if (self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectZero])
{
//adds some images as subviews here
}
```

As I understand it the initWithFrame: CGRectZero, creates a frame with size at [0,0,0,0] (essentially invisible).

When I directly set the view with

```
self.view = someView;
```

I notice the view actually displays the image. But when I add the view to as a subview of controller's 'default' view, it doesn't. So basically my question is, whats going on behind the scenes? Why is the first method "resizing" the frame and the second one not doing the same thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you see on the screen of your iPhone is almost always a hierarchy of views.

When you look at, say, your inbox in Mail, you're seeing a bunch of views.  There's a big containing view.[1]  Within that, there's a navigation bar view, a table view, and a toolbar view.  Within the navigation bar view, there's a button view on each side and a label view in the middle.  Inside the table view, there are a bunch of table cell views, and each of those cells has several label views.  The toolbar has five button views.  I could go further and talk about the views inside those buttons and so on, but I'm sure you get the idea.

The view above any given view is its superview; the views below it are its subviews.  So a table cell view has a table view as its superview and a bunch of label views as its subviews.  The top view, the one that has all the other views inside it, is called the root view.

Each view has its own drawing surface.  The rectangle formed by that drawing surface is called the frame.  The frame of a view is relative to the frame of its containing view.  So if one of our table cell's label subviews has its frame at (0,0), that means it will be in the table cell's top left corner, even if the cell is halfway down the screen.

When you're writing a view controller, `self.view` is that root view I mentioned earlier; all the other views are subviews of that one (or subviews of its subviews, etc.).  One of the features of a view controller is that it automatically resizes its `self.view` to fit the screen.  (The available area will be smaller in the middle of a phone call: the status bar is twice as high then, so there's less space for your app.  It will also be smaller if your view controller is being managed by a navigation controller or tab bar controller, but that's a different story.)  But just because you resize its root view doesn't mean that the root view's subviews will automatically resize.  To do that, you need to set their autoresizing mask (a property which tells the view how it should react when its superview changes size):

```
someView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth
                          | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

(There's a graphical way to set up the autoresizing mask in Interface Builder—click the ruler icon in the inspector window and look at the "Autosizing" section.)

Even that's not enough, though, if `someView` isn't the right size to start with.  To do that, adjust its frame before you add it as a subview of `self.view`:

```
someView.frame = CGRectMake(
                            0, // all the way to the left
                            0, // all the way at the top
                            self.view.frame.size.width, // same width as the root view
                            self.view.frame.size.height, // same height too
                           );
```

So why would you ever use subviews if you have to do all this twiddling that the root view does for you?  Simple: you can only have one root view, but one view is almost never enough for what you need to do.  If you really need only one view, of course, you can just set it as the root view and go on your merry way, but chances are, things are more complicated than that.

[1] I'm simplifying a bit here, but that's fine for right now.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a view as a subview, you need to make sure that you're actually adding to an existing view.

`self.view = view` sets the controller's view. Without this (either in code or done with a XIB) you'll never see anything as the controller has no view to show.

`[self.view addSubView: someView]` assumes that self.view is already set. If it doesn't, you're adding `someview` as a subview of `nil`, and it will never get seen.

Basically, think of `self.view` as the big container, and all the subviews are just pieces inside of it. If you don't need any subviews, setting `self.view` to a UIImageView or UIWebView is fine. If you *do* need subviews, you'll need a big, empty container view in which to put them.

In your case, I'm betting `self.view` is never set, and you're adding your image views to `nil`.

Comment: I thought of that as well, but my understanding was that when you init a UIViewController a view is automatically created - I know that's the case for the UITableViewController.

Comment: Yes this is what I understood as well. So self.view (if its nil) will call loadView, and the default loadview will create a view.

Comment: If you're not using a XIB, you need to create the view yourself. You do this in loadView.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the view controller "view" property only changes the view it is managing.

Adding a view as a subview of another view, actually adds the subview underneath the other view.

They are very different things, as one adjusts a view controller and the other alters a view hierarchy.

As a guess, the reason you didn't see anything the first way was the frame for the subview you were adding was CGRectZero (0 in size).